# Warning icon next to video file name in Adobe Creative Cloud folder?

Tags: premiere, adobe, mac

Does anyone know what this little warning icon means? It's showing up in the Creative Cloud folder, and whenever I import the video into Premiere, pressing the play button does nothing. Thanks for the help.

[image: warning icon next to file name]

Answer (score 1):

Ok minutes after posting this question, Adobe prompts me with the following error:
[image]

It's unfortunate they have such a limitation.